# Fourier transform on Hermite polynomial

Tags: integration, polynomials, fourier-analysis

> Let $h_0(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ and $h_k=B^kh_0$, where $B=-\dfrac{d}{dx}+x$.
>
> Define a transformation $T$ as $$Tf(y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-ixy}dx$$
>
> How can I find the constant $c_k$ such that $Th_k=c_kh_k$?

We can show that $h_k(x)=H_k(x)e^{-x^2/2}$, where $H_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ defined by $H_k(x)=2xH_{k-1}(x)-H'_{k-1}(x)$, but how can we go from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the $h_k$ are defined by iterated application of the operator $B$, one wants to find out how $T$ behaves with respect to $B$ for nice enough $f$. So

$$\begin{align}
T(Bf)(y) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_\mathbb{R} -f'(x)e^{-ixy}\,dx + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_\mathbb{R} xf(x)e^{-ixy}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(\left[-f(x)e^{-ixy}\right]_{-\infty}^\infty - iy\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-ixy}\,dx\right) + i \frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-ixy}\,dx\\
&= -iy Tf(y) + i \frac{d}{dy}Tf(y)\\
&= -iBTf(y),
\end{align}$$

supposing $f$ behaves well enough. Our $h_k$ are polynomials times $h_0$, so all their derivatives decay fast enough to justify integration by parts and differentiation under the integral, hence

$$Th_k = T(B^kh_0) = (-iB)^k Th_0 = (-iB)^k h_0 = (-i)^k h_k,$$

where we assumed $Th_0 = h_0$ as known.