# Differentiation under integral sign for exponential

Tags: integration, derivatives

This question arises from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570856/fourier-transform-on-hermite-polynomial):

Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial. Why is it the case that $$\dfrac{d}{dy}\int_\mathbb{R}iP(x)e^{-x^2/2}e^{-ixy}dx=\int_\mathbb{R}xP(x)e^{-x^2/2}e^{-ixy}dx?$$ I'm thinking about using dominated convergence thm, but not sure how to apply it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: I see.. so basically I need to show that both $P(x)e^{-x^2/2}e^{-ixy}$ and its partial derivative with respect to $x$ are continuous in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. But that should be clear, right?

Comment: @PJMiller: Yes, it is a nice result. Make sure you understand it.